# How to avoid duplicates bcs of __str__ function Django

Tags: django, model

I have model with Foreign Key  and i use name of that foreinKey in my template and i have 38 sql queries bcs of `__str__` funciton in my model

How can i show name of foreignKey without duplicates and similiar queries?

models.py

```
class SectionList(models.Model):
    GUID = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=True, unique=True)
    object = models.ForeignKey(ObjectList, related_name='object', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None,
                               verbose_name='Объект')
    clean_sections = models.ForeignKey(CleanSections, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Раздел'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Разделы'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.clean_sections.name}'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The answers are correct, but just to note there's a good argument to be made that you have used a bad choices of `__str__` fields here. It may even be that you want to denormalise your models a little if that field is so important. Hard to say without more context, but something to think about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `select_related('clean_sections')` to `SectionList` queryset in view

```
# views.py

def your_view(request):
    section_lists = SectionList.objects.select_related('clean_sections').all()
    ...
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'section_lists': section_lists})
```

Comment: But how can i show names in admin as well is that possible?

Comment: Yes, use [list_select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_select_related) `list_select_related = ["clean_sections"]` in admin class

Answer (score 4):

The best thing you can do is prefetching the foreign key in your queryset.

If your queryset looks like this, you can prefetch the foreign key, so your database will only be hit once for all foreign keys.

```
qs = SectionList.objects.all().prefetch_related("clean_sections")
```

Now you should see the number of queries reduced.

Comment: But how can i show names in admin as well is that possible?